# How to make a post public in Google+ without showing it on others' streams?

Tags: google-plus

I often want to make a post or album visible to the public in Google+, but I do not want to bother people by letting it show up on the streams of people who have me in their Circles.  Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you make something public it defaults to displaying on the streams of people who have you in their circle. There's no way around this except for those people to not have you in their circle or to block you. Same idea as with Facebook public posts.

Comment: That's a pity. I don't mind anybody of those visiting my profile to read whatever I post (I just wouldn't post it otherwise, I believe in no "privacy") but I just don't want some things to be pushed.

Comment: @Ivan: It's not like they're getting a notification. It's just appearing in their stream.

Answer (score 0):

Why would people circle you if they didn't want to see your posts? If you are worried that you will be seen as spamming people, you can suggest that they put you in a circle whose volume is turned down or turned off completely.

Public posts are just that - public. You shouldn't need to worry about how people will find or follow them, that is something that each person who wants to follow you can control themselves.

Comment: Let's use Picasa as an example.  I used to post a lot of photos there visible to public because I do not mind people seeing them. Actually I would like to allow them to see all of them if they come to my Picasa.  When I create an album, I usually let only certain friends or no friends know it.  I would not want to make an announcement to all my friends. Now, Picasa has been merged into G+.  Whenever I create an album, everyone who has me in his/her circile sees it in their stream.